# "Compile error: Expected: end of statement"

Tags: excel, vba

When attempting to run a piece of code containing the following if statements, I get a Compile Error: Expected: end of statement for this line `Elself IsArray(rng(J))Then`.

```
If IsObject(rng(J)) = True Then
    TempX = rng(J).Rows.Count
    TempY = rng(J).Columns.Count
Elself IsArray(rng(J))Then
    TempX = UBound(rng(J), 1)
    TempY = UBound(rng(J), 2)
End If
```

Been trying for a while now, but can't seem to make it work.

Comment: You're missing an `end if`....

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that, but the code did originally have an `end if`.

Comment: It's the typo on `Elself`, it should be `ElseIf` (with a capital " i ").

Comment: The isarray test whether the variable is an array or not, you are pointing to an object with rng(J) just put `isarray(rng)`

Comment: Oh wow. My eyes are terrible. Can't tell difference between i and l ;_;

Comment: You're not alone @findwindow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fix the `Elself` typo** and just add `End If` to the very end (on a new line):

```
If IsObject(rng(J)) = True Then
    TempX = rng(J).Rows.Count
    TempY = rng(J).Columns.Count
ElseIf IsArray(rng(J)) Then
    TempX = UBound(rng(J), 1)
    TempY = UBound(rng(J), 2)
End If
```

Note: You don't technically need the `= True` bit, you can just leave it `If IsObject(rng(J)) Then`.

Answer (score 3):

The Elself should be replaced with ElseIf (letter I not L)